# ffmpeg windows av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted failure

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to share my computer's camera with the remote computer. Local machine is linux(ubuntu 20.04.1) and remote machine is windows 10. I created virtual camera in windows machine with use OBS virtual cam and I want to share camera from local to remote machine. I could start stream from local linux machine and I got stream via windows machine. But when I try to write the stream into the virtual camera(output device), I get the error `av_interleaved_write_frame (): Operation not permitted`.

The command I wrote on the Windows side is as follows:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f mpegts -i udp://192.168.5.5:5010 -c:v rawvideo -r 30 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -s 1280x720 -f sdl "OBS-Camera"
```

The error message is as follows:
[image]

**Extra Info1:** In my experiments, if both the local and remote machines are Linux, it works successfully.

**Extra Info2:** I can view the stream that I received on windows side(remote) with the command `ffplay.exe udp: //192.168.5.5: 5010`.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Change to `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Comment: Yes it worked but it saw "OBS-Camera" as a recording file. However, "OBS-Camera" was supposed to see as a virtual camera. To give a better example, I can access virtual cam with this command "-f v4l2 / dev/video6" in Linux, but in windows the command "-f sdl" OBS-Camera "" did not work.

Comment: How can I redirect the output file to the virtual camera using ffmpeg in Windows?